# Integrating MailChimp newsletters as post

Tags: customization, newsletter, plugin-mailchimp

I have newsletters from MailChimp I'd like to include as WordPress posts. Trouble is, all the formatting in the MailChimp post makes it difficult to bring into WordPress. Is there any way to do this - what are the options?

At this point I've tried a few plugins and various copy-and-paste based methods. I may try just using an iframe in a WordPress post to show the newsletter, but I'm not sure if iframes work in WordPress posts.

Part of the challenge is the newsletter contains tables (a 2x2 grid of images) which don't seem to carry over into WordPress very well.

---

Note: there are many plugins integrating MailChimp subscriptions on WordPress, or making WordPress posts into MailChimp newsletters. Neither are what I'm after. I want to make MailChimp newsletters into WordPress posts.

Comment: Have your tried https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/olalaweb-mailchimp-campaign-manager/? It looks promising, although it seems to have some glitches, please see its reviews. If you're comfortable with programming, perhaps you'd be able to take it as a start point and enhance it to your liking.

Comment: I have tried that plugin as it seemed the most promising, but I couldn't get it working (importing newsletters from MailChimp would go on endlessly even though the API and username was valid). I may dig into that more and see if I can get it working

Comment: Does your website use ssl certificate? I got to successfully display a campaign archive within a post with the help of an iframe shortcode function. Using iframes in WP are ok as far as I know, the issue with this solution is that Mailchimp does not serve campaign archives through ssl, so it'd break on a site with ssl enabled. Let me know if you'd like me to post the function as an answer.

Comment: The site has an SSL certificate but is not totally encrypted, ie it is available as http:// - not sure if that answers whether iframes will work or not. If it isn't too much trouble, please do share the iframe shortcode function and I'll try it out. Otherwise I can keep exploring this and will write back if I'm not getting anywhere with other methods.

Answer (score 2):

Just to let you know that new version of [Mailchimp Campaign Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/olalaweb-mailchimp-campaign-manager/) plugin have been released recently.

It may be worth trying it again on your website.

It is the only existing solution to import Mailchimp Newsletter as Post in WordPress.

And it currently works on 5.1.

Let me know!