# import mailchimp newsletters into wordpress

Tags: posts, plugin-mailchimp

We send out a weekly newsletter in Mailchimp, that i'd like to be able to import into Wordpress as a post - much the same as in this thread: [Integrating MailChimp newsletters as post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250037/integrating-mailchimp-newsletters-as-post?newreg=3331c2e747604d259d76e0a809917813)

I've tried the Mailchimp Campaign Manager mentioned, it's out of date and not working. also tried Chimp Express but it wouldn't connect to Mailchimp with our API key.

would welcome any suggestions of how i might make this happen, plugin or otherwise?
TIA

Comment: Third party plugin questions are off topic here, you should ask in their support forums.